# What makes brute force attack faster?

Tags: brute-force

My question was, **What makes brute force attack faster? Is it a bigger RAM, larger storage or a faster processor**... because I saw a video of a man who put 7 GTX 1080's in parallel and it hacked a lot of passwords in less than a second using a dictionary.

Comment: All of this, depending on what the current limitation is.

Comment: Will having a larger storage result in faster brute force attacks? Or a faster RAM will make the.... In short, what will make the computer try more hashes or keys/sec

Comment: Again: all of this depending on what the current limitations are. RAM and CPU can help a lot if the process is bound on RAM or CPU speed (which it usually is). Adding more CPU will only help if the process scales to multiple CPU. GPU will help if the process makes use of it (many but not all do) etc.

Comment: *What kind of brute force attack?*

Comment: Basically, some hashing algorithm can be implemented faster against a GPU, because GPU has a different architecture of a classic CPU, to allow more parrellel computing when possible. Which is why they used one in your example, however is really depends of the algorithm, for instance, using GPU for BCrypt is meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the hashing algorithm which was used to hash the passwords.

- There are algorithms which can be implemented well on GPUs or on specialized hardware (like [FPGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field-programmable_gate_array)s).
- There are algorithms which mostly use operations which aren't very fast on GPUs so that they are bound by CPU speed.
- There are algorithms which generate large amounts of data in their immediate stages, so if you want to parallelize them, you need a lot of RAM (system ram or video ram, depending on whether you use CPU or GPU).